# Method is printing something that I am not expecting

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name, id, balance): 
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
    def print_out(self):
          return self.name, self.id, self.balance
x = Bank("Kyle", 12345, 500)
print x.print_out()
```

I am getting `("Kyle", 12345, 500)` as my output, but I was expecting `Kyle 12345 500`.

Comment: `print '%s %d %d' % x.print_out()`

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry to mention. Python.

Comment: rpattiso, I was wondering if I can change something within my code instead of having to use what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

*return* with mutiple objects returns a tuple, hence the (), and the objects are represented as they are, strings with "".

In order to have a single line with all the arguments you need to string manipulate.

try something like

```
print "%s %d %d" % x.print_out()
```

EDIT:

You can change the return condition to:

```
def print_out(self):
    return "%s %d %d" % (self.name, self.id, self.balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides writing an extra function, a class has an builtin represent attribute `__repr__` that you can modify. Every time you call in your case `print x` you get the return value of `__repr__`.

The standard value of `__repr__` is some hash.
To modify `__repr__` you can do something the following:

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name, id, balance): 
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s %d %d" % (self.name, self.id, self.balance)
```

So when you do the following

```
x = Bank("Kyle", 12345, 500)
print x
```

you get the output `Kyle 12345 500` as representation for you object